# Trying to parse links in an HTML directory listing using Java

Tags: java, html, parsing, href

Please can someone help me parse these links from an HTML page

- *http://nemertes.lis.upatras.gr/dspace/handle/123456789/2299*
- *http://nemertes.lis.upatras.gr/dspace/handle/123456789/3154*
- *http://nemertes.lis.upatras.gr/dspace/handle/123456789/3158*

I want to parse using the "*handle*" word which is common in these links.

I'm using the command  `[Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a.+href=\"(.+?)\"");]` but it parse me all the `href` links of the page.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: have you tried displaying group number 1 of your matches?

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is looking at ALL `<a href...` tags.  "handle" is always used as "/dspace/handle" etc. so you can use something like this to scrape the urls you're looking for:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a.+href=\"(/dspace/handle/.+?)\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your regex is doing something wrong. Instead of

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a.+href=\"(.+?)\"");
```

Try:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a\\s+href=\"(.+?)\"");
```

the 'a.+' on your first pattern is matching any character at least one time. If you intended to set the space character the use '\s+' instead.

The following code works perfect:

```
    String s = "<a href=\"http://nemertes.lis.upatras.gr/dspace/handle/123456789/2299\"/> " +
            "<a href=\"http://nemertes.lis.upatras.gr/dspace/handle/123456789/3154\" /> " +
            "<a href=\"http://nemertes.lis.upatras.gr/dspace/handle/123456789/3158\"/>";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<a\\s+href=\"(.+?)\"", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s); 
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.start()+" : "+m.group(1));
    }
```

output:

```
0 : http://nemertes.lis.upatras.gr/dspace/handle/123456789/2299
72 : http://nemertes.lis.upatras.gr/dspace/handle/123456789/3154
145 : http://nemertes.lis.upatras.gr/dspace/handle/123456789/3158
```